# php with jQuery script web page not loading in safari browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, visual-studio

PHP with jQuery script in visual studio is loading in all the browsers except safari browser, how do I find out the fault in the code because there debugging not able to perform in safari browser.

Comment: debugging is available as far as i know here check this https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21491?locale=en_US

Comment: .js file is debugged, but .php file including script not able to do

Comment: Then you need to debug your PHP script. We're not clairvoyant, so we can't help you without detailed information such as the script in use, error messages, and anything else that might be relevant.

Comment: there is no error in the console window. debugging php script not able to do in safari.

Comment: TypeError: Type error is showing